# Lodash sortBy function breaking the Input() binding: Angular4

Tags: angular, lodash

I have a parent component which has some cotent and I'm displaying that content in its child component. The child component received the content in the form of Angular @Input(). Because I'm binding the 'content' property in parent component with 'content' property in child component. Therefore, whenever I change the 'content' property in parent, the child 'content' property gets updated automatically. But, I'm using the Lodash's sortBy method:

https://lodash.com/docs/#sortBy

with this, I'm sorting the content and storing the sorted content in the same 'content' property in the child component. After that, whenever I make any changes to the content property of the parent component, child doesn't get updated.

Why is sortBy method breaking the binding?

Comment: could you add some code snippet to see what you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the sortBy that's breaking it, it's the fact that you store the result in the bound property.